# Installing GitLab for Slack App for Self Managed Instance

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to install GitLab for Slack app for our self-managed instance of Gitlab. We're currently using GitLab Community Edition v16.1.2. What I'm confused is that the documentation recommends for self-managed instances to use Slack slash commands but by going to this webpage, it recommends against it and instead to use Slack Apps. But, since the company I'm working for is a self-managed instance, it wouldn't be possible to use GitLab for Slack app. Thus, is Slack integration for our instance not available? Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be available with [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#gitlab-for-slack-app-available-on-self-managed-gitlab) (July 2023)

> ### GitLab for Slack app available on self-managed GitLab
>
> With this release, the GitLab for Slack app is available on self-managed instances. On self-managed GitLab, you can create a copy of the GitLab for Slack app from a [manifest file](https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests#creating_apps) and install that copy in your Slack workspace.
> Each copy is private and not publicly distributable.
>
> To create and configure the app, see [GitLab for Slack app administration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/slack_app.html).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/slack_app.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/358872).

Comment: Is `GitLab 16.2` different from `GitLab Community Edition v16.1.2`? Haven't been able to find anything that can verify this. @VonC

Comment: @MiguelTepale It seems it is different: the GitLab CE 16.2 includes this feature, while it is lacking with 16.1.x.